# Get pure value from an object

Tags: php

Anyone know how could i get the pure value out of this kind of object:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 13863
)
```

Not matter what i did, i can not get the pure value from this object. Any advise would be helpful.

Comment: @user373707: You should try to mark more of the answers to your questions as "accepted". You can do this by clicking the tick symbol to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

apply type casting like `(int) $xml->your_node_name`

details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$value = $object->{0}
```

Curly braces are often useful for accessing awkwardly-named properties on objects, particularly in the context of XML.